# Customizing HTML Dashboard Report

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to customize the HTML Dashboard for better viewing experience.

So far I achieved to have the vertical scroll bar inside the Statistics panel and freezed the Statistics Panel as a whole.

[image]

But when I scroll down, I can not see the **Headers** of the Statistics Panel.

Can anybody help me out on this.

Thanks